# How to SSO login to AWS in Docker container (using aws-sdk v3)

Tags: node.js, docker, single-sign-on, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

When developing locally, I need to have access to an S3 bucket.

The access is provided via SSO.

I'm using [aws-sdk v3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/index.html) and node.js.

When running the same node.js app without docker, I get access and everything works fine.
Here's what I do:

```bash
aws configure sso
aws sso login --profile **profile name**
```

And here's how my code looks like:

```js
const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { fromSSO } = require('@aws-sdk/credential-provider-sso');

const credentials = fromSSO({
  profile: process.env.AWS_PROFILE,
  ssoStartUrl: process.env.AWS_SSO_START_URL,
  ssoAccountId: process.env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
  ssoRegion: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  ssoRoleName: process.env.AWS_SSO_ROLE_NAME,
});

const client = new S3Client({ credentials });
```

However, when running the same app in docker (using docker compose), I keep getting the error

> The SSO session associated with this profile is invalid. To refresh this SSO session run aws sso login with the corresponding profile.

I'm using the `node:18-alpine` image and to add `aws-cli` to container, I do

```bash
docker compose run api sh

apk update && apk add --no-cache curl gcompat zip &&  \
    curl -s https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64-2.1.39.zip -o awscliv2.zip && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install

/usr/local/bin/aws configure sso
/usr/local/bin/aws sso login --profile **my profile**
```

I've checked the env variables, they're OK. However, it keeps crashing my app with the error above.

Also, here's the [contents of my docker-compose.yml](https://pastebin.com/mVnS7VQY) just in case.

---

What am I missing or doing wrong?

I feel this is a completely incorrect way to do this, but is there a better way?

SSO is my only option and I'm fine with the flow without Docker, but also really need to make this work with Docker.

---

I'm seeing at least 2 problems:

- add aws-cli installation to `docker-compose.yml`
- figure out why SSO sessions keep being invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the SSO session information was not being properly persisted within the container.

To fix that, I had to mount the `.aws` directory in the container and also add `AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/root/.aws/config` and `AWS_SSO_SESSION=my_sso_session` to environment:

```yaml
api:
  image: node:18-alpine
  env_file:
    - .env
  volumes:
    - ./api:/usr/src/app
    - ~/.aws:/root/.aws
```

My `credentials` object in app code started to look like this:

```js
const credentials = fromSSO({
  profile: process.env.AWS_PROFILE,
  ssoStartUrl: process.env.AWS_SSO_START_URL,
  ssoAccountId: process.env.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID,
  ssoRegion: process.env.AWS_REGION,
  ssoRoleName: process.env.AWS_SSO_ROLE_NAME,
  ssoSession: process.env.AWS_SSO_SESSION,
});
```

Also, newer versions of `aws-cli v2` recommend setting a session name when running `aws configure sso` (my version didn't). Hence, I modified the `~/.aws/config` file the following way:

```ini
[profile AwsDev]
sso_account_id = my_account_id
sso_role_name = my_role_name
sso_session = my_sso_session
output = text

[sso-session my_sso_session]
sso_start_url = my_sso_start_url
sso_region = my_region
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access
```

---

With this setup everything works as it should.

When the SSO session expires, I can re-run `aws sso login --profile AwsDev` and restart my docker container.

Comment: This helped me out. Different application altogether in my case but the key piece I needed was the volume mount to the .aws folder and the sso details. Thanks. 

I also suspect that the cli does not need the config change anymore. But I could be wrong, or it didn't for my python application.